# correlated subquery on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

here is table schema
`emp(no, name, salary)`

and insert data like this.

```
insert into emp values (1, 'gandalf', 3000);
insert into emp values (2, 'dobby', 4000);  
insert into emp values (3, 'legolas', 5000);
```

and I select data, like this.

```
select no, name, salary
from emp e
where salary > (
    select AVG(salary)
    from emp
    where no=e.no
);
```

but result is empty!!!
I don't understand...

I expected this
`(3, 'legolas', 5000)`

I try this query, It worked.

```
select no, name, salary
from emp
where salary > (
    select AVG(salary)
    from emp d
    where no=d.no
);
```

**So, Correlated Subquery must have to alias variable on same table?**

**At the same time, superquery must have not to alias variable?**

and I don't understand this, too.

```
select no, name, salary
from emp s
where salary > (
    select AVG(salary)
    from emp d
    where s.no=d.no
);
```

the result is empty, too..

why!!!????

Comment: Do not use correlation at all. Simply for no=1 3000 > 3000 is false. You probably want salary higher than average of all employees or at specific  department but not at employee level.

Comment: `where no=d.no` does not make sense unless you do want the average salary of several employeers with the same **no** and you got no results because there are no one with an average above itself. The problem is not the correlation is faulty logic

Comment: yes.. I understand my wrong query.... `no` is unique attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use correlation. At your example you are basically comparing employees salary with average salary (of the same person `where s.no=d.no`).

For instance for employee no = 1 you got:

```
WHERE 3000 > (3000) -- false no record returned
```

You probably want to pick employees which salary is higher than average of all employees. In that case use:

```
select no, name, salary
from emp
where salary > (
    select AVG(salary)
    from emp d
);
```

**EDIT:**

Scenario when to use correlation (`deparment_id` column added):

```
SELECT no, name, salary, deparment_id
FROM emp e1
WHERE salary >= (SELECT AVG(salary)
                FROM emp e2
                WHERE e1.department_id = e2.department_id);
```

Comment: Thank you your answer.
One more question, is it usually a bad idea to write a correlated nested query on the same table?

Comment: @b_dobee Yes, you could use correlation, but in certain scenarios (for example when comparing salary with average salary per department).

Comment: I understand, i misstake `no` is unique attribute but i try... `department_id` is not unique attribute so it worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `emp.no` uniquely identifies each row, then the average in the correlated subquery *is* the salary for that employee.  An employee's salary can never be greater than his/her salary.  Presumably you intend:

```
select no, name, salary
from emp e
where salary > (select AVG(e2.salary)from emp e2);
```

You can also write this using window functions, though:

```
select no, name, salary
from (select e.*, avg(salary) over () as avg_salary
      from emp e
     ) e
where salary > avg_salary;
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful.
I thought `emp.no` was not unique attribute. But I realize that the DB table is checked and it's defined by unique. I'm stupid....